# uploading image with volley and multer node js

Tags: android, node.js, image, express, android-volley

I am trying to upload single image to node js server with several strings. So far my code sends the image to the server as POST variables i.e. in *req.body*. While the multer in Node JS looks for image in *req.file*. Hence I am unable to upload the image and keep getting 402 Proxy Error.

**Android Code**

```
                    // String Parameters
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("title", title_text);
                    params.put("description", description_text);
                    params.put("location", location_text);

                    myServerRequest.multipartRequest(
                            URL,
                            myServerRequest.getImageByte(selectedImageForUpload),
                            params,
                            new Response.Listener<NetworkResponse>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(NetworkResponse networkResponse) {
                                    Toast.makeText(PostUpload.this, networkResponse.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    Log.i("Post UPload", networkResponse.toString());
                                }
                            },
                            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                    Log.d("Volley Error FOund", "Error: " + error
                                            + ">>" + error.networkResponse.statusCode
                                            + ">>" + new String(error.networkResponse.data)
                                            + ">>" + error.networkResponse.headers.toString()
                                            + ">>" + error.getCause()
                                            + ">>" + error.getMessage());
                                }
                            }
                    );
```

**Code for Multipart request class**

```
public class MultipartRequest extends Request<NetworkResponse> {
private final Response.Listener<NetworkResponse> mListener;
private final Response.ErrorListener mErrorListener;
private final Map<String, String> mHeaders;
private final String mMimeType;
private final byte[] mMultipartBody;

public MultipartRequest(String url, Map<String, String> headers, String mimeType, byte[] multipartBody, Response.Listener<NetworkResponse> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(Method.POST, url, errorListener);
    this.mListener = listener;
    this.mErrorListener = errorListener;
    this.mHeaders = headers;
    this.mMimeType = mimeType;
    this.mMultipartBody = multipartBody;
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    return (mHeaders != null) ? mHeaders : super.getHeaders();
}

@Override
public String getBodyContentType() {
    return mMimeType;
}

@Override
public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
    return mMultipartBody;
}

@Override
protected Response<NetworkResponse> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    try {
        return Response.success(
                response,
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    }
}

@Override
protected void deliverResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    mListener.onResponse(response);
}

@Override
public void deliverError(VolleyError error) {
    mErrorListener.onErrorResponse(error);
}
```

}

**myServerRequest Class functions**

```
public static void multipartRequest(final String url, byte[] file, Map<String, String> params, Response.Listener<NetworkResponse> success, Response.ErrorListener error) {

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);
    try {
        // the image file
        buildPart(dos, file, "avatar");
        // the string params

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
            //System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
            buildTextPart(dos, entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }

        // send multipart form data necesssary after file data
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
        // pass to multipart body
        multipartBody = bos.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    MultipartRequest multipartRequest = new MultipartRequest(url, null, mimeType, multipartBody, success, error);

    MyVolleyRequest.getInstance(Main.getAppContext()).addToRequestQueue(multipartRequest);

}

private static void buildTextPart(DataOutputStream dataOutputStream, String parameterName, String parameterValue) throws IOException {
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + parameterName + "\"" + lineEnd);
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" + lineEnd);
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(parameterValue + lineEnd);
}

private static void buildPart(DataOutputStream dataOutputStream, byte[] fileData, String fileName) throws IOException {
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"avtar\"; filename=\""
            + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

    ByteArrayInputStream fileInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileData);
    int bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

    int maxBufferSize = 1024 * 1024;
    int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    // read file and write it into form...
    int bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

    while (bytesRead > 0) {
        dataOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    }

    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
}
```

**Node JS code**

```
router.post('/upload', upload.single('avatar'), function(req, res) {

        db.uploadPost(req, 1, function(image) {

            response = {};

            // Rectify un-useful
            if(image.error) {
                response.success = false;
                response.error = image.error;
                response.data = image.data;
            } else {
                response.success = true;
                response.name = req.file.filename;
                response.thumb = image.name;
                response.type = image.type;
                //response.width = image.width;
                //response.height = image.height;
            }

            res.json(response);
        });
});
```

How can I move the **avatar** from *req.body* to *req.file*?

**updated**

Added Multipart body to request. Now getting 200 but post is still not uploading.
request object doesn't have req.body or req.file now.

Comment: You're not sending a multipart request (`multipart/form-data`), you're sending a JSON (`application/json`) request. Find an android/Java library that does `multipart/form-data` requests and it should work fine.

Comment: Is there any way I could do that way with volley that works because so far all the examples I saw uses httpClient which is decrepted

Comment: Solved it myself. The code is working.

Comment: Please share the solution

Comment: share the solution!